# Checking the number of times a string occurs in another string

Tags: python, iteration

Currently, I have a code that tells me if a string is in another string. However, I do not want it to stop the moment it finds the string. Instead, I want it to continue and tell me the total number of time it duplicates.
Eg. "110010","10"
Expected answer: 2
Given answer: 1

Below is my code.

```
def occurence(s1,s2):
    count == 0
    if s2 in s1:
        count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: "I want it to continue …" - That's the key. So what do you think does your code to continue? If there was just some statement in Python to repreatedly execute a sequence of statements …

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the func `count`.

In your case, use : `s1.count(s2)`

Comment: This is definitely the preferred method

Comment: However, what if I would like to use iteration like my question? What would be the way to go about it?

Comment: You need first to create a loop, your function as it just looks if s2 exist in s1. This can't work. I saw @GrantWilliams provide a working example ! you can refer to his example.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the s1 with slices of size of the s2 and count if the slice is equal to s2

```
s1 = '110010'
s2 = '10'
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(s1)-len(s2)+1):
    if s1[i:i+len(s2)] == s2:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

which outputs: 2

Comment: I see, yes this makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much. Even though the count function is definitely the preferred choice, this solution allows me to look at the question differently too!